# how to use Java reflection for specific types method of objects

Tags: java

```
class A{
//  target func
boolean  metohdA(){};
}


class B{
A attributeAA;
}


class C{
//I want to use reflect to call metohdA() in here ,from attributeAA, not directly instantiated A,not directly instantiated B also,B is also reflected.

void func(){

boolean b=.......metohdA();

}

}
```

I want to use reflect to call metohdA() in here ,from attributeAA, not directly instantiated A,not directly instantiated B also,B is also reflected.I read a lot of information, also didn't find it，This can be done?

Detail：

I use swing to make window programe,it contains more checkbox,so i want to use reflect to test checkbox status, call isSelected() from checkbox batch . B is window ,A is checkbox,such as B contain 100 checkboies, i want to get 100 checkboies status one by one , , of course, the 100 selection box represents 100 different functions, I through the selection box name to distinguish between different function whether chose to open it

Comment: You need to show complete, compilable code which illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: I use swing to make window programe,it contains more checkbox,so i want to use reflect to test checkbox status, call  isSelected() from checkbox  batch ,it is my plan. hava you better plan？

Comment: B is window ,A is checkbox,such as B contain 100 checkboies, i want to get 100 checkboies status one by one , hava you better plan？Is, of course, the 100 selection box represents 100 different functions, I through the selection box name to distinguish between different function whether chose to open it

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63127694/edit) your question to include details (requested in the comments). – And also you may want to have a look at [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/5698098).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class A {
    boolean methodA() { return true; }
}
```

```
public class B {
    A attributeAA;
}
```

```
public class C {

    void func() {
        try {
            Class<?> classB = Class.forName("yourPackageName.B");
            Field attributeAA = classB.getDeclaredField("attributeAA");
            Class<?> classA = attributeAA.getType();
            Object instanceA = classA.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            Object result = classA.getDeclaredMethod("methodA").invoke(instanceA);
            System.out.println("result=" + result + " : " + result.getClass());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
            | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
            | SecurityException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And

```
C c = new C();
c.func();
```

output

```
result=true : class java.lang.Boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at `MethodUtils` from apache `commons-lang`

Here some docs reference
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/MethodUtils.html

Example if you have access to the instance , but in the javadocs way more use cases.

```
MethodUtils.invokeMethod(instance, methodName, args);
```